# Java sign/verify keys and Javascript WebCrypto verification fails

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, digital-signature, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to

1. generate sign/verification keys (RSA)
2. sign a value (using those keys) on a Java web application (lets call server-side)
3. in order to a web client to verify - public-key imported as `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` + `SHA-256`,  (in a browser, using [WebCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) / client-side)

I'm having problems verifying the signed value (signed in the Java server-side) even though the public sign/verify key is successfully imported as a JWK in the client side.

I was wondering if there is any **algorithm compatibility** issue in any of the steps (OpenSSL, Java or Javascript) that I may be encountering.

The OpenSSL commands used to generate the keys

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -pubout > publickey.pub
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in privatekey.pem -out privatekey-pkcs8.pem
```

Importing keys with Java (server-side)

```
public static KeyPair generateSignKeyPair() throws ... {
    byte[] privBytes = b64ToByteArray(PRIVATE_KEY_PEM_VALUE);
    byte[] pubBytes = b64ToByteArray(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM_VALUE);

    // private key
    KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

    // public key (javaPubSignKey)
    X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubBytes);
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(X509publicKey);

    return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
}
```

Signing a value with Java (server-side)

```
 public static byte[] generateSignature(PrivateKey signPrivateKey, byte[] data) throws ... {
    Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    dsa.initSign(signPrivateKey);
    dsa.update(data);
    return dsa.sign();
}
```

Send them to a web-app for the WebCrypto API to verify as a client/browser (the client is aware of the publicKey generated in the first step).

```
// Import public sign/verify key (javaPubSignVerifyKey)
var signatureAlgorithm = {
    name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: {
      name: 'SHA-256'
   }
};
// JWK format (1)
crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'jwk', javaPubSignVerifyKey, signatureAlgorithm, false, ['verify']
).then(success, error);

function success(key) {
    signatureVerifyPublicKey = key;
}
```

Note (1): on the Java side, I'm using `com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK` to export the publicKey to JWK format.

The sign key is successfully imported by WebCrypto. But when it comes to the verification, it fails (the verification boolean is `false`).

```
crypto.subtle.verify(
      signatureAlgorithm,
      signatureVerifyPublicKey,
      signature,               // bytes in Int8Array format (2)
      data                     // bytes in Int8Array format
    ).then(
       function (valid) {
           // valid === false
       }
    )
```

Note (2): also note that every example I found on WebCrypto used `Uint8Array` to represent byte arrays, but since Java generates **signed** byte-arrays I need to use `Int8Array` so that the signature values are not contaminated (maybe this is an issue aswell).

**EDIT:** for reference, it turned out to be another unrelated issue - I was converting the expected data from base64 twice in Javascript without noticing it; naturally the verification failed.

Comment: java `byte[]` stores values from 0..255. I think you need to to use `Uint8Array` and `ArrayBuffer`. Could you try to use the `stringToArrayBuffer` function documented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018233/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-digital-certificate-with-javascript-webcrypto-api/37407739#37407739 to represent `data` and `signature`?

Comment: Thank you, still not working. Maybe I need to change the fundamentals of the implementation: thinking on importing a X509 certificate in Java and using `pki.js` + `asn1.js` to extract the publicKey from it (certificate) in Javascript for WebCrypto to verify ([example here](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/blob/master/examples/certificate-decode-example.html))

Comment: I guess it is not a problem with the public key, because it had raised an exception when you imported the JWK. But, to ensure it, you can import it in `spki` format (binary RSA key converted to ArrayBuffer)

Comment: When importing `spki`, generated with `Base64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded())` in Java, and imported with `str2ab(atob(spkiBase64))` in Javascript the symptom is the same: verification fails.

Answer (score 3):

Please, check this simple code based on yours to **import a RSA public key (spki) and verify a signature.** I have generated the keys and signature using similar Java code

```
var publicKeyB64 = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVdZDEs6htb3oxWstz7q+e5IwIRcptMNJiyemuoNyyjtiOy+0tEodjgo7RVoyUcGU3MysEivqvKdswQZ4KfwQCBLAR8DRzp3biAge5utZcKsQoQaC1rCEplfmzEo5ovIlBcMq5x1BxnrnlwEPRmM7MefRa+OeAOQJcstHcrJFO7QIDAQAB";
var dataB64 = "aGVsbG8=";
var signatureB64 = "aEOmUA7YC5gvF6QgH+TMg0erY5pzr83nykZGFtyGOOe+6ld+MC4/Qdb608XiNud+pBpzh0wqd6aajOtJim5XEfCH8vUPsv45aSPtukUIQTX00Oc1frIFDQI6jGJ4Q8dQYIwpqsyE2rkGwTDzt1fTTGiw54pLsJXjtL/D5hUEKL8=";
var signatureAlgorithm = {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),hash: { name: 'SHA-256'  }};

//convert public key, data and signature to ArrayBuffer. 
var publicKey = str2ab(atob(publicKeyB64)); 
var data = str2ab(atob(dataB64));
var signature = str2ab(atob(signatureB64));            

crypto.subtle.importKey("spki", publicKey, signatureAlgorithm, false,["verify"]).
    then(function(key){
        console.log(key);
        return crypto.subtle.verify( signatureAlgorithm, key, signature, data);                    
}).then( function (valid) {
    console.log("Signature valid: "+valid);
}).catch(function(err) {
    alert("Verification failed " + err );
});
```

I could not reproduce exactly the issue. Using the `str2ab` utility function you have linked, the code works perfectly.

```
//Utility function
function str2ab(str) {
  var arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
  for (var iii = 0; iii < str.length; iii++) {
    bytes[iii] = str.charCodeAt(iii);
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

I suggest to compare both codes to find the differences

Comment: Hi @pedrofb, thanks for your feedback - it turned out to be another unrelated issue: I was converting the expected data from base64 twice in Javascript without noticing it; naturally the verification failed. For reference, using `Uint8Array` caused no problem whatsoever as I was initially suspecting.

Comment: Also the `str2ab` and `ab2str` methods that I used are like [this](https://gist.github.com/nunofaria11/6fa749066cb821c6e55f160e03a98889)

Comment: Perhaps you were having problems from using `Uint16Array`?

Comment: I have checked the code using the `str2ab` function you have provided, and works good. In fact, the content of the function is the same code I was using in `stringToArrayBuffer`. I think the problem with the previous `str2ab` was `Uint16Array`. I have updated the anwser with the proper links