# Custom Plugin for browser which interacts with system

Tags: java, cryptography, applet, pkcs#12, iaik-jce

I was using applets to use the IAIK cryptography framework to generate PKCS#12 keystore and use it for signing.

Now since from JAVA 9 applet support is stopped so now I cannot use applets anymore.

Is there any way where I can create custom plugin for browser and that plugin will interact with JVM or will execute any dll which consist my cryptography logic and after processing return the result back to browser.

Or instead of plugin any other approach where I can use the IAIK framework to do my process may be JavaScript or something.

Or any other JavaScript cryptography that supports PKCS#12.

Any Suggestions please.

Comment: It is not possible to use Java or DLL from the browser, nor to create a plugin that has access to this type of resources. If you need digital signature and support for pkcs # 12, you can use the WebCryptographyApi. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018233/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-digital-certificate-with-javascript-webcrypto-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will look into WebCryptographyApi.  Also It means from plugin I cannot call any api or program?

Comment: Using javascript you can launch an external application installed on device. For example, if that application embeds a web server, you could stablish a communication channel to "localhost"